# How can I implement a kraus_error in qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, noise

I have successfully run `bit_flip_error` in Qiskit by function `pauli_error`, but I can not find how to implement a `kraus_error`.

`pauli_error` works as follows:

```
pauli_error([('X', p_reset), ('I', 1 - p_reset)])
```

`kraus_error`?

Comment: Could you please do it by copy-paste? Screenshots are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can implement it a similar way you implemented the `pauli_error`, just with different parameter input. You need to pass in a `(list[matrix]): Kraus matrices`. The `kraus_error` method is defined [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/stable/qiskit/providers/aer/noise/errors/standard_errors.py#L32). You should be able to import it from the same module you import `pauli_error` from: `qiskit.providers.aer.noise.errors.standard_errors`

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it!

Comment: It seems that the link became invalid.